# How to change the order of the div-blocks?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How to change the order of the div-blocks with media-queries?

Comment: Are you asking how to resize and move elements around visually? Or how to actually change the HTML markup?

Comment: YES!!how to resize and move elements around visually

Comment: Please update your question with what you actually want to do. There are many questions/answers on Stack Overflow for media-queries already, so it wouldn't hurt to be specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.  CSS is specifically for changing style to present markup.  Media Queries are specific to CSS.  They are not for modifying the markup.

Comment: What you need is to use javascript to detect the view information on the client OR you need to use a device detection library in the server code and deliver dynamic content.